# org.talend not found in custom component

Tags: java, talend, talend-mdm

I am building the custom component for the Talend using the component template, found on the Talend repository, by using the wiki I have created the component. successfully compiled the jar. installed the jar, I am able to see the component in the palette.but I got an error when I drop the component in the job designer. **when I run the job it always says org.talend not found**

> Execution failed : Job compile errors  At least job "Test2" has a
>   compile errors, please fix and export again. Error Line: 502 Detail
>   Message: org.talend cannot be resolved to a type There may be some
>   other errors caused by JVM compatibility. Make sure your JVM setup is
>   similar to the studio.

Comment: Which component template did you use? Where in the component does the string org.talend occur?

Comment: thanks for your comment, the issue has been resolved. I will post the complete answer with all of the resources soon.